# How to Verify the email sent by PHP, not by syntax; but by status

Tags: php, email, verify

I did verify email address entered in the textbox, before sending mail i.e by syntax. But How to verify or validate the correct email address using PHP?

```
if(mail($emailto)) {
   echo("status=Sent");
}
else {
   echo("status=Failed");
}
```

For example if you enter xxxxxxxxaddfb54@yahoo.com, it accepts as a valid email id! Hw do we know it exists or not?

Comment: You cannot.  PHP hands the message to the SMTP server, and the SMTP server delivers it to the receiving SMTP server.  It _does not_ communicate anything back to PHP. The sending server may get a bounce back for an invalid user.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. You can't tell whether an email address exists or not yourself -- only the remote mail server knows that. Most mail servers are kind enough to tell you afterwards if you've sent to a nonexistent mailbox, though.

Comment: Many servers do not tell you whether or not the address exists.  Spam prevention, poor configuration, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. That's the nature of the internet: You can't be absolutely certain any host (let alone an account on the host) is in a given state at any time unless you have control over the host.

You can tell a failure by a return message from the mailer daemon specifically stating that the delivery attempt failed. But that is a courtesy most private mailers will not extend to you.

You will almost NEVER get a return verification email in the case of successful delivery unless you have specifically set up the server to behave that way.

Answer (score 0):

The user will tell it for you when reading :)

You can't as already stated, so be sure to provide a "**please resend me the email**" link around, so the user will be able to put the correct email [if he or she was wrong], or just to send it again if there were any issues with you smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell whether an email address exists (unless the server you are trying to contact has some sort of API for this).  You can, however, check whether the *domain* can be emailed to:

```
function checkEmailDomain($email) {
   list(,$domain) = explode('@', $email);
   if (checkdnsrr($domain, 'MX')) {
      return TRUE;
   }
   else if (checkdnsrr($domain, 'A')) {
      return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

Note that this is not 100% dependable either.  If you want to use it, it should be purely advisory.